# Find a factorization for $P(z)=z^5+z+1$ with $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-numbers, factoring

> Find a factorization for $P(z)=z^5+z+1$ with $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

I am a bit confused actually. Is anyone is able to give me a hint to solve the problem involving complex numbers?

I think I can use a finite geometric series.

Comment: This looks like $z^2+z+1$ which is a factor of $z^3-1$. So, any root of $z^2+z+1$ is a root of $P$ as well. This gives one of the factors.

Comment: A possible strategy is to decompose it as $(a+1)(b+1)$, and reason about the degrees of each term. It works in this case, but it is not an universal technique.

Comment: Factorising this into linear factors [is horrible](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E5%2Bz%2B1)

Comment: Another way to do that is: $z^5+z+1=(z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1)-(z^4+z^3+z^2)$, where the first portion is $(z^6-1)/(z-1)=(z^3-1)(z^3+1)/(z-1)=(z^2+z+1)(z+1)(z^2-z+1)$, and the second portion is $z^2(z^2+z+1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like actual trial factorization. If it factors over the rationals (with no rational root) then Gauss content lemma says that it factors over the integers. There are just two possibilities, one of them works.
$$ (x^3 + A x^2 + B x + 1)(x^2 + C x + 1), $$
$$ (x^3 + A x^2 + B x - 1)(x^2 + C x - 1). $$
See if you can solve for $A,B,C$ integers in either one